# Fetch polyfill not working on Edge (or IE)

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I'm trying to POST a request (Form) using the fetch polyfill "whatwg-fetch". While this works in Chrome and FF, it doesn't seem to work on IE and Edge.

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
const dataObject = {
    'a' : 'b'
}
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('someData', JSON.stringify(dataObject));                         

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  mode: 'cors', 
  cache: 'no-cache', 
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
  },
  redirect: 'follow',
  referrer: 'no-referrer', 
  body: params, 
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch((e) => {
   console.log(e);
});
```

In IE and Edge this code does not send the request and catches an exception:

```
e Failed to execute 'fetch()' on 'Window': Invalid argument.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where is `data` defined?

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, fixed code.

Comment: Well `URLSearchParams` is not supported in IE and Edge. Try using `query-string` package and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and in my case helped to add header like this and **.toString()**: 
`...
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            body: form.toString()**
...`

Answer (score 0):

**Hi - so it does appear to be a loading problem.**

you just try

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>` 
in **index.html** and check is it working.

Comment: Adding a new script tag to the page is not a possibility, I tried adding the babel-polyfill to the webapack 'entry' and as an import in the JS file but it still didn't work.